# Como subir e configurar um projeto com Laravel no servidor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Estou iniciando com **Laravel 5.3** e aprendendo a explorar todos os seus recursos. Mas estou com uma dúvida. Como ficaria esse meu projeto no servidor (em produção). Hoje meus projetos estão dentro de uma pasta com o arquivo index.php na raiz. O que mudaria em um projeto utilizando Laravel?

Comment: Servidor dedicado ou compartilhado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você sobe um projeto Laravel para o servidor, você deve configurar o Virtual Host  para apontar para a pasta `public` do seu projeto, pois como o nome da pasta diz, essa é a pasta que deverá ser pública.

Pensando no caso do Apache2 , você poderia configurá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nome-do-projeto/public
    ServerName www.nome-do-projeto.com.br
    ErrorLog /tmp/nome-do-projeto_apache.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Também é necessário remover o arquivo `.env`, uma vez que o mesmo só deve ser usado em ambiente de desenvolvimento.

O arquivo `.env` afeta diretamente as configurações dos arquivos na pasta `config`. Por exemplo, o arquivo `config/database.php` deverá conter no segundo parâmetro da função `env` o valor referente às conexões em produção, pois o primeiro parâmetro tratar-se-á dos parâmetros definidos no arquivo `.env`. Na falta deste arquivo, o segundo parâmetro da função `env` será considerada para sua configuração.

Exemplo:

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'url-do-banco-em-producao.com')
```

No arquivo `.env`

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

Ou seja, você precisa apenas enviar os arquivos da sua aplicação para  a pasta específica no servidor, com exceção do arquivo `.env`.

Answer (score 2):

Além do cuidado com o arquivo .env, conforme já respondido acima, caso vc não tenha acesso/controle para configurar um virtualhost, vc pode fazer o seguinte:

Supondo que seu document-root seja a pasta 'www' ou 'public_html':

- Copiar apenas o conteúdo da pasta 'public' do seu projeto para o
  document-root;
- Editar o arquivo 'index.php' para referenciar os
  diretórios existentes no arquivo corretamente;
- Editar o arquivo 'server.php' que fica na raiz do seu projeto para apontar para o 'index.php' do document-root.