# Como subir api do laravel em servidor compartilhado

Tags: php, laravel, servidor

Estou tendo dificuldades em subir minhas api laravel no servidor compartilhado.

Meu frontend é em angular, eu dei um ng build --prod e através do FileZilla transferi para a pasta `public_http` no servidor hostgator.

O laravel eu passei todas as pastas do meu projeto para o `public_http`, acessei por ssh o servidor e instalei o `composer`. Através do ssh eu consigo acessar a pasta public_http e rodar, por exemplo "`php artisan serve`". Minha dúvida é como fazer minhas api rodarem no meu domínio. Ex: www.dominio.net/api/login
Todos meus arquivos laravel já estão na pasta public_http, porém se eu tentar acessar a api através do meu domínio eu recebo 404.

O que está faltando?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como subir e configurar um projeto com Laravel no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224859/como-subir-e-configurar-um-projeto-com-laravel-no-servidor)

Comment: Esse var/www seria o nome do meu dominio? Quando eu olho no hostgator no gerenciador de arquivos o caminho para a pasta public é: /home4/cademe47/public_html/public, tenho que colocar isso no DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer o seguinte:
se voce na hora de instalar o  Laravel deu ao seu projeto o nome de api, a pasta a qual deve colcoar os arquivos deve ser como o exmplo abaixo.
www.dominio.net/api/

depois de subir os arquivos tente:

1 - Entre no arquivo .env e edite as credenciais do banco de dados, coloque as credenciais do banco de dados da hostgator.

2 - Executar `composer install`

3 - Executar `php artisan key:generate`

4 - Executar `php artisan migrate`

Comment: e depois? até ai deu certo, o problema é executar o serviço do laravel no servidor para rodar no dominio

Comment: você esta falando em php artisan serve?

Comment: sim, tem que rodar no servidor ?

Comment: a principio não, seu sistema ja deve estar pronto e funcionado a este ponto

Comment: se eu tento acessar meu dominio/api/login da erro 500

Comment: tente isto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93609/discussion-between-gustavo-richter-and-veronesecoms).